# How to create simple login form from json webservice

Tags: android

I am new to the technology.So i stucked in webservices. I have created the simple login form.This is my Mainactivity class in which i have done simple webservice connection parse the data throgh json object. I just want to login from my username and password from my webservice,but i am unable to do so.I have given the internet permissions also.Can any one tell me whats my mistake.suggest some solutions.

```
package com.example.shrutir.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
    /**
    * Created by shruti.r on 3/5/2016.
    */
    public class Test_login extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

      //  new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

         Button sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
        final EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usrname_dr);
          final EditText passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pswrd_dr);

        sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();


            }


        });


    }

    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
        EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usrname_dr);
        EditText passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pswrd_dr);


        String yourJsonStringUrl ="Here is my json webservice url";

        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {



        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("GetUserLoginResult");

                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString("UserName");
                    // String lastname = c.getString("LastName");
                    String password = c.getString("Password");


                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + name + ", lastname: " + ",     

             password:" + password);


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

           if (usr.equals("name")&& passw.equals("password")){
              Intent m = new Intent(Test_login.this,Newpage.class);
                startActivity(m);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login 

        Sucessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

        }
        }


    }
```

This my xml file : Here i have created simple login form with username and password

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f1f1f1"
android:weightSum="1">
<!--   android:background="@drawable/loginbg"-->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="458dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usrname_dr"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="   Username"
        android:background="#FCFCFC"
        android:textColorHint="#666666"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#10c1b9"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:textSize="15dp"

        android:id="@+id/pswrd_dr"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint=" Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#10c1b9"
        android:background="#FCFCFC"
        android:textColorHint="#666666"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frgtpaaswrd"
            android:textColor="#415052"
            android:text="Forget Password?"/>


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Remember Me "
            android:textColor="#415052"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:onClick="sign_in"
        android:background="#10c1b9"/>




    <Button

        android:id="@+id/sign_up"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:background="#415052"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what's problem you are facing ? Its not clear.

Comment: I want use my webservice username and password and sign in.but i dont know to how to do it in same code. can you tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

variable name and password should be public

Your Mistake

```
usr.equals("name")&& passw.equals("password")
```

it should like

```
usr.equals(name)&& passw.equals(password) // variable not string
```